# Receiving "Disallowed Key Characters" error in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following message: Disallowed Key Characters and the string producing the message seems to be

```
__utmt_~42
```

I am just trying to load the page and for the life of me can't figure out why this is happening. It started out of nowhere. How can I locate the source of this?

Comment: Which string, where ? In a query string ? When you call what ? We need more details.

Comment: That is what I am not sure about. I just try to call the main page, there are no forms being submitted or anything else. How can I find where it would originate from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had a similar problem, so, for the sake of Google search results:

__utmt is a cookie. More specificly, a Google Analytics cookie. The ~Number part probably means it's a copy/duplicate. Think of it like the word.doc~1 files that are stored on your computer when working in a Word doc.

So first, check your Analytics code on the website, is there a duplicate somewhere? 
My problem was solved by altering this duplicated line:

```
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-1234567-89");
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-1234567-89");
```

Weird thing is that the file always had this duplicated line of code, for as far as my GIT goes back. It might be a change in the way analytics code handles cookies...

Oh, and the "Disallowed Key Characters"  part. That's normally a good thing, protecting your CI app against evil.

Its in the system\core\Input.php file.

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)) {
    // there is no ~ in this regex pattern
    // You could add it, but you probably end up breaking other stuff ("/^[\w:~\/]+$/i")
    exit('Disallowed Key Characters');
}
```

Comment: This stuff all seemed to occur during a ddos attack that affected some of our systems. Some of our users are now complaining that they are getting the disallowed key characters warning message. As I couldn't find the duplicated, I was wondering if there is some way to reset all of our users cookies for our site?

Comment: Hi, you could alter your Input helper a little bit (file: system/core/Input.php) but this is certainly not the best method.

In method _clean_input_keys you coud add:

`if (preg_match("/^[\w:\/]+~[0-9]+$/i", $str)) {
 // this is causing the problem, try unsetting it
 unset($_COOKIE[$str]);
} else {
 exit('Disallowed Key Characters');
}`

Also, you could could add everything after the if statement in an else. Tested and works for me.

`if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)) {
 // Disallowed Key Characters part

} else {
 // fetch clean string
 // and return $str;
}`

Comment: What do you mean by clean string, can you provide an example? Also is there anyway to unset cookies using a regex? Would unsetting a google analytics cookie have unforeseen consequences?

Comment: This should work, you can replace all code in the function that causes the problem. It tries to unset the __utmt_~42 cookie types, if it failes (probably...) then it just ignores the cookie.(Code not tested, I don't have CI on this PC.
`if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)) { 
 // Disallowed Key Characters part 
 if (preg_match("/^[\w:\/]+~[0-9]+$/i", $str)) { 
  // this is causing the problem, try unsetting it 
  unset($_COOKIE[$str]); 
 } else { 
  exit('Disallowed Key Characters'); 
 }
} else { 
 // fetch clean string 
 // and 
 return $str; 
}`

Answer (score 6):

Follow the following steps

1. Search for **function _clean_input_keys** on **/system/core/Input.php**
2. update this **exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’);** to **exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’ .  $str);**

Answer (score 2):

Change on **system/core/Input.php**

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
                {
                      exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
                }


to 

if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-~]+$/i", $str))
                {
                      exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just going to comment, but I do not have enough reputation, apparently. I had a similar problem this morning. It was being caused by a cookie (__utmt_~1). My site does create a cookie called __utmt but not with the single underscore, tilde and 1.  I suspect that __utmt_~1 is a duplicate of the original cookie, but I am not sure how it was created.  However - clearing my cookies stopped the Disallowed Key Characters message.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have this problem with recaptcha of google 
(POST variable named `g-recaptcha-response`)
in my case was solved adding a escaped hyphen at the end of the listed characters
like this:

```
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[~a-z0-9:_\/-\|\-]+$/i", $str)){
```

to the file **system/core/Input.php**

Answer (score 0):

Though its a old post, its still relevant today as the message is cryptic and brings the website to its knees in no time.

In my case, in the test system, all of a sudden, started receiving this message for every page that gets an user input through GET/POST. Later found that to be the result of additional filter I added recently to the php.ini as below, which promised, to configure the default filter to behave exactly like htmlspecialchars().

```
[filter]
filter.default = full_special_chars
filter.default_flags = 0
```

On removing these filters from the php.ini file, the error was gone. Hope this helps somebody who encounters the same problem.